# How to create a variant of re-sizeable and fixed size containers

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, unions, variant

I have a class whose underlying data is a variant of `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr` and `std::deque`. This is shown in the code below.

```
template<class T>
class matrix2d
{
private:
    typename std::variant<std::vector<T>,
                          std::unique_ptr<T[]>,
                          std::deque<T>> data;

public:
    matrix2d<T>() = delete;
    matrix2d<T>(size_t h, size_t w, int type) {
        try {
            switch (type) {
            case 0:
                data = std::vector<T>(h*w);
                break;
            case 1:
                data = std::make_unique<T[]>(h*w);
                break;
            case 2:
                data = std::deque<T>(h*w);
                break;
            default:
                throw std::runtime_error("Unrecognized type of matrix2d class data");
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    auto operator[](size_t i) {
        return (std::begin(data) + i);
    }
};

int main()
{
    matrix2d<int> a2d(4,5,0);
    for (size_t i{}; i<4; ++i) {
        for (size_t j{}; j<5; ++j) {
            a2d[i][j] = 5.0;
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are as follows:

Is it OK to create a union of a `unique_ptr` and the other resizable containers?
 
Also, how can I overload the subscript operator [] to make the class function as a two-dimensional array?

Comment: One question per question. For the constructors there is no difference. Equivalent.

Comment: Prefer enum (class) over simple int for type for readability.

Comment: What is the point to choose container type at runtime? You pay runtime overhead for each access moreover... :

Comment: @Jarod42 Agreed. But the point is to have the option to choose whichever container I want at any given time. As for runtime overhead, that's why I was wondering if there's a better way of allocating space for the containers. Perhaps, using std::visit?

Comment: I meant than I understand usage of `std::variant<int, std::string>`, but not `std::variant<std::vector<T>, std::deque<T>>`. So using `std::visit` will indeed to fix compilation but the purpose of the class is unclear for me.

Comment: @super Point taken. I have edited and reduced number of questions to 2

Comment: note that your loop on the rows is offset by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant is valid.

The usage for accessing rows however requires different treatment for `std::vector<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` *on one hand* and for `std::deque<T>` *on the other hand*. As `vector` and `unique_ptr<T[]>` use contiguous memory, elements of a `deque` are not required to be stored contiguously.

Let's assume we want first to implement operator[] only for vector and unique_ptr.

### Step 1

We need to add to the class a member that would hold the size of a row, this is required in order to calculate the position in the array of row number i.

So let's suppose you add a private member 'w':

```
size_t w;
```

and that you initialize it in the constructor:

```
matrix2d<T>(size_t h, size_t w, int type) : w(w) {
   // ...
```

### Step 2

Now the operator[] that we are looking for can look like this:

```
auto operator[](size_t i) {
    return std::visit([i, w = this->w](auto&& arg){return &arg[i*w];}, data);
}
```

The use of `std::visit` is required even though we use the same operation here for any of the types managed by our `std::variant`. However,  `std::visit` is also able to have different operation for each of the types stored, see [std::visit on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

### Step 3

If we want to support `deque` as well, this requires a different treatment.

Currently our operator[] returns T* and we want to keep it.

For deque, we cannot just take the address of the first element in a row and assume that all elements in the same row are adjacently stored right after, contiguously. So to allow the use of deque with the same approach we need at least the rows to be contiguous. We can achieve that with a deque of vectors of Ts. This may look like this in the `variant` declaration in class:

```
 std::variant< std::vector<T>,
               std::unique_ptr<T[]>,
               td::deque<std::vector<T>> > data;
```

And in the constructor, the initialization for the `deque` would be:

```
case 2: { // TODO: use enum instead
  auto d = std::deque<std::vector<T>>(h);
  for(auto& item : d) {
    item = std::vector<T>(w);
  }
  data = d;
}
break;
```

operator[] would be changed now to:

```
auto operator[](size_t i) {
    return std::visit([i, w = this->w](auto&& arg){
        using U = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<U, std::deque<std::vector<T>>>) {
            return &arg[i][0];
        }
        else {
            return &arg[i*w];
        }
    }, data);
}
```

---

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/192fbf6705aecc7c

Comment: In the answer, I noticed that there is a change in the ordering of the included headers. Is there a particular reason for the re-ordering?

Comment: No. I haven't seen your includes.